# Creating a bug report from when the app crashes on the phones of testers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bug-reporting

I'm wanting to have a bunch of people beta test my app on their phones soon. In the event that the app crashes, what's the best way for them to send me a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own experience: I used Flurry as the analytics tool in my project. I followed Flurry's recommendation and set up an uncaught exception listener inside my code.

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    [FlurryAPI logError:@"Uncaught" message:@"Crash!" exception:exception];
}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    [FlurryAPI startSession:@"my_API_here"];
        ....
}
```

And then I tested my app, and after several hours' delay, I was able to see a few crashes reported to Flurry. Things like this:

> NSInvalidArgumentException:
>   -[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x2e1b30 Msg: Crash!

It's neither complete nor thorough, but it was a convenient way to have a basic sense of what's going on out there in the wild.

Comment: Flurry is great service, and this is a great way to go. Also have a look at the section "Addresses and symbols outside the debugger" at http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html He describes how to process crash reports (which apple will supply to you) from outside your app. I believe users have to opt in for this, so something like flurry is more reliable, but when it comes to debugging, the more information the better.

Comment: Thanks Gavin for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 5):

A good approach is to use a 3rd party service like [Instabug](https://instabug.com) which is a bug & crash reporting service that allows for two things:

- Automatically receive crash reports in the event of a crash
- Allow users to report bugs through a shake gesture in-app.

All reports arrive to your Instabug dashboard containing various details such as:

- Network and console logs
- Complete Device details
- Visual reproduction steps
- 3D inspection of the current view hierarchy
- Crash stack trace (In case of a crash report)
- It only takes a line of code to integrate.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a database for it. Have a submit form that places their report into the database. This way any of the info they submit can be searched and managed easilly.